# How to pre populate generated files in Code Magic for flutter

Tags: flutter, cicd, codemagic, flutter-objectbox

I am trying to use object box in flutter application. It gives two files on pub run one `objectbox.g.dart` and other one `objectbox-model.json`.

The former file is ignored in `gitignore`.

Now that we are trying to use Code Magic to implement CD, we are facing the problem as generated file is not available in Code magic cloud. How to let Code Magic use this generated file. Also, how to update it when this file changes.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the code generation task to your codemagic.yaml:

```
workflows:
  default-workflow:
    [...]
    scripts:
      [...]
       - flutter packages pub get
       - flutter pub run build_runner build
      [...]
[...]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding additional information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I think this is very basic and a flutter developer should be capable to understand a that simple example. At least in my opinion